# CX_freeze EXE file only working with webcam but not working with Network camera

Tags: windows, cx-freeze, ip-camera, yolov8, ultralytics

I have converted python program with ultralytics for custom object detection using cx_freeze into exe file, my exe file working fine with webcam. but when i convert the same with network camera its neither not working nor throwing errors. my program works perfectly with pycharm IDE. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

i want to convert my python project to convert into exe file using cx_freeze. i tried to convert using pyinstaller and py to exe but i got ultralytics error with those method. finally i converted using cx_free and its running with my webcam only.

but i want to connect with network CCTV camera , that program works with pycharm, but after converting to exe file its not working. i dont even get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you launching .exe file by double clicking? If so, the command prompt will close at the same time as the error appears on the screen resulting in you unable to see the error.

Open the command prompt and navigate using cd command to the folder or just drag and drop the .exe into command prompt and press Enter.

Comment: Sorry for the answering like that, I would love to post in the comment section but don’t the reputation for that.